# Firebase Storage no export named useStorageEmulator

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building a react application with typescript and am looking to host it on firebase. I want to use cloud storage to store content to serve and to test it locally before I deploy it. I am trying to get the storage emulator to work.

Following the guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage
I am attempting to use the storage emulator hook it describes:

```
import { getStorage, useStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";
```

But I get the following error from typescript:

```
Attempted import error: 'useStorageEmulator' is not exported from 'firebase/storage'.
```

The documentation mentions this is from the new v9 sdk: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade .
I have tried a few versions different versions with no success. Currently I have this version in my `package.json`:

```
"firebase": "^9.0.1"
```

I have also tried a few other versions including `9.0.0` and `^9.0.0-beta.8` but they all give me the same error.

The error seems genuine to me as when I looked in that file I don't see any export with the name `useStorageEmulator`. But considering it's front page in the documentation I figured it's more likely that I have something wrong on my side.

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's just a mistake in the documentation. It was renamed due to conflicts with React's naming conventions. The  function is actually called `connectStorageEmulator`. There's a PR to fix the documentation which should clear up the confusion in the future.